# simple problem apps snapcraft - minimize buttons

Tags: minimize

compare the look of google chrome and vlc, visual studio code

sure you already saw the minimize buttons in snapcraft applications vlc and vcode do not appear and also appear differently than chrome

all native and elementary store apps work fine but snapcraft apps like vlc and vcode don't work well

before the last system update everything worked fine in all applications including snapcraft

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check and accept the answer if this solution works for you - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/22004/12483

**Please make a comment if this do not work.**