# Elementary OS Hera updates create problems

Tags: updates, release-hera

I just really want my EOS good again. Today's update makes my EOS Hera not good / comfortable anymore. Here's the problem:

**1.** Minimize button is dissappear on some apps like *Blender, Inkscape, and Chromium*. Even after setting it up on *Tweaks* Settings.

[image]

**2.** I can't disable *dynamic-workspaces* anymore. Via command line or via *dconf* editor. Both didn't work.

*Actually i like *dynamic-workspaces*, but the fullscreen behaviour is the problem for me. It switching the workspace, also it create an issue to some apps. I hope i can fullscreen several windows in current workspace.

Should i wait for another updates? or there are solution? Thanks

Comment: I have found solutions for the both points. Can you check does it works for you also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new update in order to make not only fullscreen but also maximized applications to go to a new space automatically and there is a **call for testing** on another website. Probably because of this feature the option for switching on and off the dynamic workspaces is removed, I cannot say if it will be changed or not after the next updates, but for the present moment there are some fixes:

## 1. Buttons layout fix

If you want the buttons to be on the right side, move the semicolon(:) before their names

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

## 2. An option to change the fullscreen behaviour

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
```

prevents opening a fullscreen app on a new space for me. Replace the false with true on the line above in order to restore the default behaviour.

Comment: it works thanks!